# Assign a VLAN higher than 10 with a Netgear GS110EMX switch and Netgear switch manager

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, switch

(Reposted from [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/80871/edit))

I have a Netgear GS110EMX Smart Managed Plus Switch.

I need to be able to communicate with the main network on one port (set it to 192.168.something), with my laptop on another port, and with homemade devices on the remaing ports (for instance, 10.0.X.X).

I was told the way to do this is to set the VLAN addresses in the manager. Like, set "10" for 8 ports, "192" for two ports. I might be wrong though.

I use the Netgear manager page, that you reach by entering the switch's address in your browser.

What I would like to do is:

- Set one port to a VLAN with the main network
- Set  8 or so ports to a VLAN of 10, for instance, to communicate with the homemade devices
- Keep one VLAN to communicate with my computer.

The pages of the manager look like that:

Basic settings page:
[image: Netgear switch manager]

Advanced settings page:
[image: Netgear switch manager, advanced settings]

The problem is that I can only set the VLAN from 1 to 10. If I type another number (20), the box empties itself.

**What can I do to route my switch to the networks addresses that I want?**

Apologies for the beginner question, I'm not too good in network engineering.

Answer (score 1):

When using port-based VLANs, you're limited  with their numbers up to quantity of ports.
https://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/GS110EMX/GS110EMX_UM_EN.pdf#unique_24

You need to use IEEE 802.1Q standard for whole range of VLANs (next option in menu). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1Q